# LibGdx: Change Entire Package name for all projects

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I want to rename my entire Package, i.e `old.and.bad` to `new.and.good`.

When I try to Refactor->Rename the Core-project, it only offers me the option to rename the last identifier of the package, in the above example "bad".

Same for trying to rename the Android project.

How can I refactor so every project (ios, android, core) change every part of their name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In Android Studio, you can do this:

For example, if you want to change `com.example.app` to `my.awesome.game`, then:

1. In your ***Project pane***, click on the little gear icon ( [image: Gears icon] )
2. Uncheck / De-select the `Compact Empty Middle Packages` option

[image: Compact Empty Middle Packages]

3. Your package directory will now be broken up in individual directories
4. Individually select each directory you want to rename, and:

   - Right-click it
   - Select `Refactor`
   - Click on `Rename`
   - In the Pop-up dialog, click on `Rename Package` instead of Rename Directory
   - Enter the new name and hit **Refactor**
   - Allow a minute to let Android Studio update all changes
   - *Note: When renaming `com` in Android Studio, it might give a warning. In such case, select* **Rename All**

[image]

5. Now open your ***Gradle Build File*** (`build.gradle` - Usually `app` or `mobile`). Update the `applicationId` to your new Package Name and Sync Gradle, if it hasn't already been updated automatically:

[image: Refactor Directories]

6. ***Done!*** Anyways, Android Studio needs to make this process a little simpler.

Solved by **Sheharyar** !

Comment: What if I wanted to change from com.awesome.game to awesome.game? (Note that com is removed.)

Comment: I think you would just need to open the Project View, and move the awesome folder beneath the src, and delete the com one